# Why does derefrencing a raw pointer gives a segmentation fault if there is no shared reference to the value pointed at?

Tags: pointers, memory, rust, raw-pointer

Running the following code gives a segmentation fault:

```rust
fn main() {
    let val = 1;
    let ptr = val as *const i32;
    unsafe { println!("{:?}", *ptr) };
}
```

Output:

```
[1]    69212 segmentation fault (core dumped)  cargo r
```

However, when `val` is put in as a reference `&` while declaring the raw pointer, the code runs as intended and as `val` is printed out.

```rust
fn main() {
    let val = 1;
    let ptr = &val as *const i32;
    unsafe { println!("{:?}", *ptr) };
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

So what is the shared reference doing here and why does the program fail without it? Isn't a reference in rust also a pointer with extra schematics? Why to we need to create a pointer to a reference and not directly to the `val` itself?

Comment: Try `println!("{:?}", ptr)` to print out the memory addresses in each case. Can you guess why dereferencing one of those addresses succeeds while the other fails?

Comment: The first one dereferences `0x1`, an invalid pointer. The second takes a reference to `val` and then dereferences it, which is valid.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! So does this mean that the assignment of a raw pointer using `*const` without a shared reference invalid? Why is the memory address `0x1` if there is no reference?

Comment: Because you put `0x1` in it yourself. Your first code is equivalent to `let ptr = 1 as *const i32;`.

Comment: The problem is with the `as` operator, that is able to convert an integer into a pointer directly, but that created pointer is meaningless.  If you avoid the `as` with `let ptr: *const i32 = &val;` it will work but with `let ptr: *const i32 = val;` it will fail to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue can be answered by looking at the different semantics of the both code lines you provided.

```
fn main() {
    let val = 1;
    println!("{:?}", val as *const i32); // Output: 0x1
    println!("{:?}", &val as *const i32); // Output: 0x7ff7b36a4eec (probably little different)
}
```

Without the reference the value of the variable is take as it is to be used to dereference the memory. This leads of course to a segmentation fault, since it will be not in the allowed address range of the program.

Only when the reference operator is used, the address of the variable is casted to a raw pointer, which then later can be dereferenced without any segmentation fault.